# What words can I use to express two separate relationships instead of "the relationship between" phrase?

Tags: word-usage, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, vocabulary

I measured the relationship between A and B and then the relationship between A and C separately. Now I need to form my title based on those two separate analyses. When I use "The relationship between A, B and C" it sounds like I studied a model and I don't want to mislead the readers. Is there a usage like "The relationship of A with B and C"? What are the alternatives of "the relationship between" phrase?

lf you help me I will be grateful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think your sentence 'relationship of A with B and C' is quite correct and appropriate, myself.

Answer (score 1):

I might make "relationship" plural to make it more obvious, for example, "The Relationships of A with B and C". This states very clearly that there is more than one. Other than that, sounds fine to me.